# Adding a watermark with programming code on a video so that it gets activated if it does appear on a website instead of the original

Tags: video, programming

Hello I would like to know if is there such a way has to inject programming code into a video, so that for example if the video gets ripped from different websites, that video loses all the video properties or becomes corrupted and displays a watermark like saying :  Do not support stealing video views.

Because I do know that many sites gets away stealing millions of views, and not crediting the proper content creators, so I wanted to know if there was such a way, so that it doesn't happen, and that if the video gets uploaded through another website and gets ripped the code that was injected on the video itself, gets activated and in that way corrupting the video , or disabling the video part.

There would still be a way of recording the screen with such a program, but it would become more difficult doing so.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts as a programmer:

You can make make watermark hardcoded in the video, and remove it with the script in your player. For example you add big text "STOLEN" in your video but not with white or semitransperent font color, but with inverted color of every pixel. Like that:

[image]

After that, player on your site will invert those pixels again on the fly. You will always put your "STOLEN" watermark in same place, so you will need to hardcore position of the text in the player only once.

In that way only player on your site will know how to correctly remove watermark.

However it will be pretty easy to look into code of your player, to find all hardcoded information, because player will be running in the user's browser, what means in the users PC.

Comment: it probably won't work quite that well as expected because of compression artifacts but the idea itself is pretty good

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that I should patent this idea? =)

Answer (score 0):

**No.** At the moment, there is no video container that can contain DRM code. You would have to build an entire DRM-system around it, which would result in a bad user experience. Also, every DRM can be cracked (Though this might not be true in the future. There is [Denuvo](http://www.denuvo.com/) which is used with game DRM and hasn't reliably been cracked yet). Just put your watermark on the video and inform the audience about their rights. If you see your video on another website, you can request a [DMCA takedown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) or something similar depending on the jurisdiction of your country. You can also [contact Google](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905) to have unauthorized publications of your content removed (from Youtube, Search Results et c.)

This answer is somewhat incomplete because you haven't mentioned how your video will be distributed.

Comment: I did put on my comment that it was youtube , but nowadays more and more people are ripping the videos from youtube downloading them and putting them on facebook, stealing and don't giving proper credit, and facebook doesn't do a single thing even if you tell them to remove.

Comment: I don't see that comment anyway. In this case, there is absolutely nothing you can do except the watermark thing. Even if there were a way to do this, Youtube would reject the video or the DRM would be lost upon [Youtubes reencode](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/will-compression-format-of-audio-change-when-uploaded-to-youtube/15815#15815). Well that's just how the internet works, can't really do anything about it. Again, if you see your video being used unauthorized, it's your intellectual property and you can take any legal steps you feel are appropriate

Answer (score 0):

There is fundamentally no way to do this. If you can display a video so that someone can see it, then it can be copied or stolen. Various types of DRM can push control to different areas, but even if you could control every part of the chain including the end user's PC and monitor, they could still use a video camera.

So your only realistic solution is to place a visible tag so you know where the video has come from. This still does not prevent piracy or copying (you can't) but it raises the awareness.